# How to connect VLP-16 velodyne to indigo?

Tags: ros, vlp-16, vlp16, ethernet, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under Ubuntu 14.04, indigo,
My situation now is:

```
      sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.77
```

(in new ternimal)

```
      roscore
```

(in new terminal)

```
      cd ./catkin_ws  
  source devel/setup.bash
  roslaunch velodyne_pontcloud VLP16_points.launch
```

in new terminal:

```
 rostopic echo /velodyne_points     However, there is no data printed.
 rostopic echo /velodyne_packets   It is said:"Cannot load message class for [velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan]. Are your mess ages bulit?"
```

Whether I powered and connected the lidar to my computer or not, there seems to be no difference in the results above.

I think this means the velodyne lidar wasn't connected to linux OS. Is it true?

Therefore, how to connect VLP-16 velodyne to indigo?  How to connect the lidar with my computer through the ethernet?
I only need to power the lidar and connect the lidar to my computer by the Ethernet line, and I don't need to do anything else? For example, I need to turn off wifi or change some network settings in my linux system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261330/how-to-connect-vlp-16-velodyne-to-indigo?/) by [T318forever](https://answers.ros.org/users/30306/t318forever/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error message has nothing to do with connectivity to the velodyne. It means that rostopic echo does not know about the `velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan` datatype. And this is likely because it's in your workspace. However in your 2nd terminal you have not source the setup file. Try running

```
cd ./catkin_ws  
source devel/setup.bash
```

before you try to echo.

I'd recommend reviewing the catkin tutorials especially: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [T318forever](https://answers.ros.org/users/30306/t318forever/) on 2017-05-09**:
It doesn't make any difference. Still no data is published